# using tidyverse's pivot in order to produce long format

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe:

```
df -> tibble(Readmission10_LOS = c(0.55, 0.39), 
           Readmission10_Deceased = rep(TRUE, 2), 
          Readmission30_LOS = rep(NA, 2), 
          Readmission30_Deceased = rep(NA, 2))
```

I would like to "elongate" this data frame using `pivot_long` in order to get to the following shape:

```
df_long -> structure(list(readmission = c(10, 30, 10, 30), LOS = c(0.552, 
NA, 0.3, NA), Deceased = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I tried:

```
df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(
everything(),
names_to = c(".value", "readmission"), 
names_sep = "_"
 )
```

but it does not produce the expected result.

Any ideas?

Comment: check out the function `gather()`

Comment: @akash87 I did and pivot long is supposed to be easier, for some reason it is not working

Comment: Don't use `gather` it's depreciated. `pivot_longer` is the way to go ;) **But** I was not able to run your example: Please check the code for `df`.

Comment: @dario should be ok now

Comment: It's still not ok, since your arrows are pointing the wrong way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_pattern = "readmission(\\d+)_(\\w+)",
               names_to = c("readmission", ".value"))
```